# formatting links within a list from external css style sheet

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to format some links within an unordered list using an external stylesheet, when the links are moused over they should increase in size and be displayed blue. My syntax is below:

HTML

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#dejaview"><img src="imgs/dejaview_lft.gif" width="95px" height="75px" alt="Dejaview"
             title="Click for more info"/>Dejaview</a>
        </li>
```

There are three more links below this before the UL ends

Stylesheet

```
ul.a:hover
    {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: blue;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here, I can't work it out.... I have tried both li.a:hover and what is currently above, and I was under the impression that if I wanted to change the format for all links within a list I didn't need to create a class for them. I could be wrong though, I'm a n00b to CSS

Thanks

Rick

Comment: `ul.a` means `any ul element that has class "a"`. Try `ul li a:hover { ... }` instead.

Comment: While the answers pointing out your CSS errors are correct, they may not reflect the extent of your problems. If you make the suggested changes and still get no luck after refreshing your cache look into the Cascade part of CSS and also Specificity (which is often poorly understood). The cascade means your style may be replaced by a style "closer" to the affected element, ultimately, inline styles win. Specificity means the more specific rule is applied: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: The suggested correction fixed the issue, simple syntax error on my part. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li a:hover
    {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: blue;
    }
```

Should work

because the dot '.' in before 'a' stands for a class called 'a'

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is wrong.
You need to edit like below.

```
ul a:hover
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: blue;
}
```

ul.a:hover will work when your code like below; '.' means 'class'.

```
<ul class="a">
<li>hi</li>
</ul>
```